# Fetch Azure sync table on new device

Tags: c#, azure, synchronization

I have an Azure app service setup for `SyncTables`. On my development machine, I can save items and they sync to the cloud, no problem. However, I am having a hard time getting the data to a new device. I assumed that when first loading the application on the new device that the `table.PullAsync()` calls would fetch all the data for each table.

The push/pull process completes successfully, but no data is pulled to the device. I can add a new item on the new device, and it uploads to the cloud, but I am not having any luck getting the initial data onto the new device. Here is my `SyncAsync` method:

```
private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Person> personTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<Person>();
private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Card> cardTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<Card>();

private async Task SyncAsync(bool showMessage)
{
    string errorString = null;

    try
    {
        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        await personTable.PullAsync("person", personTable.CreateQuery());
        await cardTable.PullAsync("cards", cardTable.CreateQuery());
    }
    catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex)
    {
        errorString = "Push failed because of sync errors: " +
            ex.PushResult.Errors.Count + " errors, message: " + ex.Message;

        errorString = ex.PushResult.Errors.Aggregate(errorString, (current, error) => current + ("\r\n" + error.Result));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorString = "Pull failed: " + ex.Message +
            "\n\nIf you are still in an offline scenario, " +
            "you can try your Pull again when connected with your Mobile Service.";
    }

    if (errorString != null)
    {
        // TODO: log some sort of error message
        MessageBox.Show(errorString);
    } 
    else
    {
        if (showMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database synchronization complete.");
        }
        LastSynced = string.Format("Last Synced: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

As I said, new data created will sync to the new device, but I need to be able to do an initial pull of the data when the application is installed on a new device. Is there a way to force the `PullAsync()` call to fetch all data, or somehow to make the `SyncTables` know that they have data to fetch so that the next time `SyncAsync` is called, they will fetch the data?

Here is my `InitLocalStoreAsync()` method, which initializes the local database on application launch. I have also tried deleting the `localstore.db` file and launching again, hoping that the fresh copy of the file would want to pull all the data, but that wasn't the case.

```
private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
{
    if (!MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
    {
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
        store.DefineTable<Person>();
        store.DefineTable<Card>();
        await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

One thing I'm thinking is that maybe for now I will have to make sure all instances of the software are installed before adding any data, but I want to get this figured out in case of adding more installations in the future.

**EDIT 2**

I tried to fetch the data from the remote database manually and import it into the new installation, but that caused the items to be duplicated on the server after the next sync.

**EDIT 3**

Installing multiple instances prior to adding any data also did not work. Both instances can push data to the remote server, but neither are fetching the new data as they should. I'm hoping that it is something simple like a setting somewhere, but I don't have this problem with another Azure app service that I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I was trying to use the old NuGet packages `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` and `WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore`. Changing to use the new `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` and `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore` packages got everything working properly.

One of the things that is different is that the new Azure system properties no longer contain the leading `__` so the old packages didn't know how to compare what data was new on the server.